# Testing with Rspec - The correct way

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, tdd

My weakest point when it comes to coding, is using TDD & BDD methods - I tend to just write code.. but it is something that I am trying to work on.

Could anyone point out the best way to go about the following problem:

Class1:

```
module TempMod
    class MyClass

        def initalize(config)
            @config = config
        end

        def process(xml)
           if react_upon? xml.something
              puts 'yeah'
           else
              puts 'nah'
           end
        end

        def react_upon?(xml_code)
            #code here
        end

     end
end
```

So lets say I wanted to test this class, or build it from a TDD point of view so I write my tests:

```
describe TempMod::MyClass do

   let(:config) {double}
   let(:myclass) {TempMod::MyClass.new config}

    context 'Given that the xml is something we react upon' do
        it 'should check that it is valid' do
           myclass.process '<some><xml>here</xml></some>'
        end
        it 'should output yea'
    end
end
```

How do I test that it is calling the react_upon? method. Do I even want to see it is calling it?

Is the proper way to test it, to test all the functions like the react_upon? itself independently of the other functions?

This is properly the main thing that is most confusing me with this sort of testing. Am I testing the whole class, or just individually testing the functions, and not their interactions with the other functions in that class?

Also I realize the the react_upon? might not adhere to the Single responsibility principle and I would probably move that out to its own module/class which I could test using a stub.

If anyone can shed some light on this for me that would be awesome.

edit:

```
describe TempMod::MyClass do

  let (:valid_planning_status_xml) {
    '<StatusUpdate> <TitleId>2329</TitleId> <FromStatus>Proposed</FromStatus> <ToStatus>Confirmed</ToStatus> </StatusUpdate>'
  }

  let(:config) { double }

  let(:status_resolver) { double }

  subject(:message_processor) { TempMod::MyClass.new config, status_resolver }

  context 'Given that the message XML is valid' do

    it 'should check the context of the message' do
      expect(message_processor.process valid_planning_status_xml).to call :check_me
    end

    context 'Given that the message is for a planning event update' do

      it 'should call something' do
          pending
       end
    end

    context 'Given that the message is for a recording job update' do
    end

    context 'Given that the message is for a video title update' do
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question confused me a bit is this what you are asking

```
module TempMod
  class MyClass
    def initalize(config)
        @config = config
    end
    def process(xml)
       react_upon?(xml.something) ? 'yeah' : 'nah'
    end
    def react_upon?(xml_code)
        #code here
    end
  end
end
```

Then test like

```
 describe TempMod::MyClass do

   let(:config) {double}
   let(:myclass) {TempMod::MyClass.new config}

   context 'Given that the xml is something we react upon' do
     it "should respond to react_upon?" do 
        expect(myclass).to respond_to(:react_upon?)
     end
     it "should react_upon? valid xml" do
       expect(myclass.react_upon?(YOUR VALID REACTION GOES HERE)).to be_true
     end
     it "should not react_upon? invalid xml" do 
       expect(myclass.react_upon?(YOUR INVALID REACTION GOES HERE)).to be_false
     end
     it "should say 'yeah' if it is valid" do
       expect(myclass.process('<some><xml>here</xml></some>')).to eq('yeah')
     end
     it "should say 'nah' if it is invalid" do
       expect(myclass.process('<some><xml>here</some>')).to eq('nah')
     end
     it 'should check the context of the message' do
       expect(myclass).to receive(:react_upon?).with('<some><xml>here</xml></some>')
       myclass.process('<some><xml>here</xml></some>')
     end
   end
 end
```

Right now your tests have no expectations so I added one that expects `myclass` to respiond_to the `react_upon?` method and another that expects `myclass.process(xml)` to respond with a `String` that equals `yeah`.

Comment: Sorry, Its trying to get whats in my head out! The point that i am getting at, is with the expect that you put in, that is testing the whole class (including the react_upon? method) is that the way which i need to be testing it? or do i test the react_upon? method in a seperate expectation, to make sure that it is doing what i need it todo?

Comment: @Vade I have no idea what the react_upon? method looks like but I added an expectation for that too now.

Comment: thats the one! i was using the wrong call. i was using expect(myclass).to have_recieved(:react_upon?) Thank you!

Comment: @Vade I also just added 2 expectations to test the actual `react_upon?` method directly.

Comment: Is it possible to (or correct to) test to see if the myclass.process calls the method react_upon?, does the tests care wether it does call it or not? in my new example i have something like myedit in my orginal questions

Comment: @Vade not sure if this is what you are asking but I added a spec test to test that your class `received` a call to `react_upon?` with the `xml` you could change this to `receive(:react_upon?).once` or `receive(:react_upon?).with(anything)`. anything means I don't care what I pass to it just care that it was called.

Comment: Thank you, that was what i needed. I had some confusion about how the expect(xxxx).to receive worked. I didn't know if it actually called the method, or if it stubbed it. which it does seem to do (tested this with a puts msg in the actual function i was expecting to receive) Thanks again for your input